# Unzip Voxceleb dataset on Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, dataset, unzip

I am trying to use voxceleb dataset for some audio classification. I use this command to download the dataset:

```
!wget --user=.... --password=... https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/voxceleb/vox1a/vox2_dev_aac_partaa
```

and using `filetype`, I know that it's a zip file. However, when I try to unzip it, from python as well as through terminal, I'm not able to. Here are the error:

Through Python:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 with zipfile.ZipFile(f,'r') as zip_ref:
> 2     zip_ref.extractall("audio_data")
> 3 # !unzip vox2_dev_aac_partaa -d audio_data
>
> 1 frames /usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
> 1196             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")    1197
> if not endrec:
> -> 1198             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")    1199         if self.debug > 1:    1200             print(endrec)
>
> BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

And through the terminal, after running the following command `unzip vox2_dev_aac_partaa -d audio_data`:

> unzip:  cannot find or open vox2_dev_aac_partaa,
> vox2_dev_aac_partaa.zip or vox2_dev_aac_partaa.ZIP.

What should I do?

Comment: Try to manually login and download the file and unzip it. See if that works, if it doesn't then there is something wrong with the file itself

Answer (score 1):

You need to download all the zip files provided in the [dataset](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/data/voxceleb/vox2.html) and concat them as mentioned.

Also, there seems to be an authentication issue when using wget, so I tried curl.

```sh
# Download all 8 files similarly.
curl -o vox2_dev_aac_partaa.zip -u <your username>:<your password> https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/voxceleb/vox1a/vox2_dev_aac_partaa
```

Then concat them as mentioned in their website

```sh
cat vox2_dev_aac* > vox2_aac.zip
```

Then unzip it.

```sh
unzip vox2_aac.zip -d audio_files
```